# Compare Dates with nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

I have the below table.

```
ID     StateDate       EndDate
 1     01/01/2018     01/30/2018
 2     02/15/2018     02/01/2018
 3     02/01/2018
```

I need to compare dates, SQL below.

```
select *
from tablea a
where 1=1
  and a.startDate<= EndDate
```

Expected Results :

```
ID     StateDate       EndDate
 1     01/01/2018     01/30/2018
 3     02/01/2018
```

How can I ignore the Nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a high date value if endDate is null then your condition still holds true. See below:

```
select *
from tablea a
where 1=1
  and a.startDate<= coalesce(EndDate,TO_DATE('12/31/9999', 'MM/DD/YYYY') )
```

Comment: I like this idea but I'm getting a "Inconsistent datatypes; expected Date got CHAR

Comment: my mySql might be different to yours. I updated my answer.

Comment: It's not MySQL at all - the question is tagged Oracle

Comment: You're right. Wrong function and i updated my answer.  User: John accepted it because of the idea.

Comment: What if the value of `startDate` is greater than 01/31/9999? The maximum date in Oracle is 12/31/9999.

Answer (score 2):

Null is not a value, it's the lack thereof. Using it with any operator that expects a value, such as `<=` will return null (i.e., "unknown"), which is not true, and thus the row won't be returned.

You could explicitly check for it with the `is` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablea a
WHERE  startDate <= endDate OR (startDate IS NOT NULL AND endDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Best part of this solution is that it works with all flavors of sql. Thanks @Mureinik !

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `OR` keyword to `where` clause like:

```
select *
from table a
where (a.startDate<= EndDate) 
OR (a.StartDate is not null and a.EndDate is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablea a
WHERE a.endDate is not null
AND a.startDate <= a.endDate
```

Let me know if you have question!

Comment: this will not return ID=3. pls check again.

Comment: The requirement was to exclude ID=3 because its has 'null' end date.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following. I think this is the most compact way of doing it:

```
SELECT * FROM tablea a
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND a.startDate <= COALESCE(a.endDate, a.startDate);
```

If the value of `endDate` is NULL, the `COALESCE()` function will replace it with the value of `startDate`, which is always equal to itself and hence, always greater than or equal to itself.

Hope this helps.